# How to use ExifInterface with a stream or URI

Tags: android, stream, orientation, uri, exif

I'm writing an app that can be sent a photo URI from the "Share via" menu in Android.

The kind of URI you get is `content://media/external/images/media/556` however `ExifInterface` wants a standard file name. So how do I read the exif data (I just want orientation) of that file? Here's my (non-working) code:

```
Uri uri = (Uri)extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

// This line doesn't work:
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(uri.toString()); 
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
```

Any help (other than "you have to write your own ExifInterface class") is appreciated!

Comment: did you try new ExifInterface(uri.getPath()); also, you may be able to query the content uri for orientation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer randomly in the Facebook Android SDK examples. I haven't tested it, but it looks like it should work. Here's the code:

```
public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
    /* it's on the external media. */
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);

    int result = -1;
    if (null != cursor) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            result = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: hello @timmmm, I tired this code,for finding the orientation of image using photouri. But cursor is throwing nullpointer exception may be it is not getting photouri. Could you suggest any solution for it.

Comment: @timmmm in the code above you forgot to close cursor - it's a memory leak

Comment: @Gregory Facebook forgot! Thanks for fixing the code. Btw this is why garbage collection is rubbish - you can't use RAII.

Comment: Note that this returns the literal orientation in degrees, not the enum representing the value like ExifInterface does.

Comment: @JustinMeiners I'm using ExifInterface and StrictMode is picking a detectLeakedClosableObject and killing my app (penaltyDeath)

Comment: For image uri's not coming from a media store you can open the URI as a stream and then read the exif data using this library https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get an ExifInterface using a filename string or InputStream, by doing importing the support ExifInterface in your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.1.0'
```

then:

```
private getExifInterfaceFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(uri.getPath());

    return new ExifInterface(stream);
}
```

Remember that in Android there are multiple Uri types and you may need to use a Content Resolver and other approaches to get the real path from an Uri.